# which is the best Camera API for image processing in Android

Tags: android-camera-intent, android-camera2, android, opencv

I am working on an Android project which should capture an image by the camera API and the do some image processing to classify the image and give result to user (I used opencv to process the image and classify result). My question is which is the best camera API? Shall I use Java camera view in opencv or use Camera API using intent or finally use camera 2 API which can give me control to manage some characteristics related to ambient conditions.

Please clear my confusion and suggest which is the best one to control the quality of the image and and other conditions that affect the image taken.

Answer (score 0):

native camera:

1. higher framerate
2. capture RGBA, no need to convert from android yuv format
3. and much more features

so i would say use standard Camera API

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you say standard camera API, which one I listed do you mean? Can you please give me an example using code in Android?

Comment: i mean android native camera api 2 and take a look at this hope it helps [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html)

Answer (score 0):

try gpuImagePlus library  which is available for both android and ios.
here is the link for android version.
https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it.